# unable to fetch list of image from sqflite

Tags: flutter, sqflite

#i am saving the images picked from gallery to sqflite as String but i am unable to fetch list of all the images inside my images i converted my selectedimages to base64 and store it in images

```
  final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  List<File> imageFileList=[];
  String images;
  void selectImages() async {
    List<XFile> selectedImages = await imagePicker.pickMultiImage(imageQuality: 50);
    if (selectedImages != null) {
      for(int i=0;i<selectedImages.length;i++) {
        imageFileList.add(File(selectedImages[i].path));
        debugPrint(selectedImages[i].path);
      }

      for(int i=0;i<selectedImages.length;i++){
        final bytes = File(selectedImages[i].path).readAsBytesSync();
        String base64Image = base64Encode(bytes);
        images = base64Image;
      }

    }
    setState((){});
  }
```

#the images are saved but i am getting back only on image when i try to see using

```
Image.memory(base64Decode(savedHomeworkImages))
```

#like is there a proper way to save list of gallery picked image to save in sqflite and receive it in and render that list of image in view? i am stuck here need your guidence